# php button onclick to activate hidden button

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

How to create a button for user to click and it will show hidden button

case: on a product auction page, user need to click "unlock button" to unlock the bid function

```
 <button id="unlock_bid">unlock bid</button>
```

---

```
 <div id="auction_product_form" style="display:none">
   //auction product function
 </div>
```

---

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#unlock_bid").click(function(){
                $("#auction_product_form").css("display","block");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! You will need to post what you have tried so far in order to get an answer - no one will write you code for free from nothing!

Comment: Wouldn't that need to be JavaScript rather than PHP? Using PHP implies a submit to the server.

Comment: @droopsnoot i had update with my code

Comment: @Lennon Goh OK, I can't help, I don't know much CSS or JavaScript, I only commented because you were asking how to do it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

By default when you enqueue jQuery in Wordpress you must use jQuery, and `$` is not used (this is for compatibility with other libraries).

You have to actually pass `$` into the function call:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#unlock_bid").click(function(){
                $("#auction_product_form").css("display","block");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```